# When are you not supposed to use the shrinkwrap & lock files that NPM produces?

Tags: node.js, npm

Recent NPM versions have started automatically producing `package-lock.json` files, making it easy for all the devs on a team to make reproducible builds. Previously, one had to manually instruct NPM to produce a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file, so it's a lot more convenient now that this happens automatically.

But what are the cases for when you are *not* supposed to use these files? I am especially interested in this from [the view of a package maintainer](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/pull/1604) of open source software published on NPM.

This is what I have come up with so far:

### Non-published software: any

(Only lives in a repo)

On teams that produce some internal non-published software, you can choose to use whichever lock file you prefer. Both will make development smoother.

### Published software: depends

(to a registry like npmjs.org)

#### Applications: shrinkwrap

If you are developing a daemon or CLI app, ship it with a shrinkwrap file. A `package-lock.json` will not do as it won't be published with NPM packages.

#### Libraries: nothing?

Don't create a shrinkwrap file, ref  [`npm-shrinkwrap.json` is discouraged for libraries](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/shrinkwrap.json):

> The recommended use-case for npm-shrinkwrap.json is applications deployed through the publishing process on the registry: for example, daemons and command-line tools intended as global installs or devDependencies. It's strongly discouraged for library authors to publish this file, since that would prevent end users from having control over transitive dependency updates.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what the docs say. package-lock.json is for apps. Libraries should rely on package.json and work with all versions of the dependencies within declared boundaries.

Purpose of the package-lock.json is dead simple - to lock dependencies to the exact versions once they were resolved. It makes sense only on application level, as applications are not supposed to be a dependency for anything else.

Libraries in contrast are not applications, and are expected to have apps that depend on them. The more versions of own dependencies a library supports the less chances of unresolvable version conflicts with other libraries. So package-lock.json is something completely opposite to what libraries should have.

Comment: Just to be sure; my current understanding was correct?

Comment: I doubt so. I won't pretend I understand where published/unpublished things came from, nor why there should be any difference between cli/desktop apps. I have updated the answer with a bit more verbose explanation if it helps. Please decide yourself if you current understanding is correct.

Comment: The publish status is actually important. The package-lock file is not published, whereas the shrink-wrap file is. To me, it seems one could use the first, but not the latter, in published libraries.

Comment: None of them are for libraries. Shrinkwrap is for apps. You put the exact quote in the question.

Comment: I am talking about using the `package-lock.json` for development. I don't see much of a downside: it doesn't affect the life of package consumers, and makes the development faster (package resolution on `npm install`). The only (slight) downside I can see is that you don't catch possible regressions when new versions of dependencies that are allowed by your semantic version strings are published. But then again, you are never guaranteed that, unless you reinstall everything every time.

Comment: Anything stops you to keep it locally for development? I don't really see a reason to make it a part of the history.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158019/discussion-between-oligofren-and-alex-blex).

Comment: If you don't `package lock` or shrink wrap libraries, how do you prevent one of your dependencies  from introducing a breaking change?  I think we all know we can't trust "semantic" versioning to save us from that.

Comment: @NSjonas you do package lock, but only on application level. It makes no sense to lock on library/package level.

Comment: @AlexBlex that makes sense... Although that does mean that at any given moment in time your library might not be "buildable/runnable".  This happened to me today... I tried to run a "hello world" for a library and it failed because one of it's dependencies had a breaking change in a minor release.  

The only solution is to manually update your application package lock, but if you're just getting started out it's very hard to know what broke.  

Is there any way to prevent this as a library maintainer?

Comment: @NSjonas That's what community is for. Once unintentional BC was introduced by the  downstream dependency, somebody will notice it and file a bug.  Both you and app developers can update **package.json**  as a tactical measure and then you have some time to upgrade your library to be compatible with newer version of the downstream dependency.  It seems to be the most pragmatic approach but if you have a better alternative in mind, please share your thoughts.

Comment: @AlexBlex unfortunately I don't (which is why i am here)...  I guess if you have concerns about the stability of a particular dependency (maybe it's still experimental or you can't trust the maintainers), then maybe you consider "pinning" it?  Although, whose to say which projects are "trustworthy"?  In this particular case it was the typescript AST that broke the build!

Comment: @NSjonas If you "pin" it too narrow (and the .lock is the extreme case of using **particular** version) your users won't be able to resolve dependencies when more than one library depends on the same downstream dependency. People tend to go with optimistic approach and trust other libraries. It allows to reduce maintenance efforts for the cost of increased risk of the BC brake from dependencies. Once the BC is reported you cap the highest compatible version in your package.json. Other approaches seems to cause more problems or are too expensive for opensource projects